# Is it appropriate to edit and properly format a really bad question?

Tags: discussion, edits

I am seeing a growing number of people who edit a question for grammar, tags, or formatting when it's clearly off topic, not clear what is being asked or no effort was put into the question.

I usually bypass editing those questions if it's clear the question is going to get tossed anyway for being poor.

Is it appropriate to edit and properly format a really bad question?

Comment: Save your time and edit a good question instead.

Comment: if its going to be closed and/or deleted anyways no save your time. Edit a good one instead like user438383 said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the question is unclear and editing will help to make it more clear and possibly make it a good question, then of course it should be edited keeping in mind to fix everything possible.

If it is off-topic then most of the time editing won't help though some questions can be reworded to make them on-topic.

If there is no effort (which usually lends to too broad of a question) then they probably shouldn't be edited at all.

I see this a lot, also, and it makes me sad. If it is in the review queue, I will usually reject the suggested edit and leave a comment that unsalvageable posts shouldn't be edited. If 2k+ users are editing them then there's not much to be done about it.

**tl;dr** if it's unsalvageable then there's no sense in doing anything but downvote and flag/close. If an edit can bring it up to par then it should be done.

Comment: @davidism well, they are getting rewarded with a potential badge. But yes, I would say the suggested edits are more of a problem which is why I added my practice for when I see them in the queue.

Comment: FWIW I sometimes edit solely to help other voters see that question is worthy of closing. This regularly happens when there's wall of text (that may bring voter to doubt, "maybe I missed something"). Simply breaking the text into readable paragraphs reveals what it's worth. "Blahblahgimmecodezblahblah" -> "Blah blah -- gimmecodez -- blah blah"

Comment: Thanks for the answer...its my personal feeling too. If I can help reword it a little to make a better question, I will. I think the ones that are obviously dud questions are usually being edited by people looking for that extra +2. I am working my way up to being able to cast close votes on those questions..

Comment: @davidism - If the question eventually gets deleted the +2 is deducted.

Comment: @gnat Very good point. I sometimes edit and close vote, hoping that the edit made it clear to other close voters that it should actually be closed.

Answer (score 23):

Do not suggest edits to irredeemable questions. If a question cannot be edited to be on-topic (by other users than OP), then suggesting an edit is a waste of your time as an editor, and the time of any of the reviewers. And it adds yet another suggested edit to the review queue which is at its limits even at the best of days. Part of the problem is edits that really do not do anything useful, even if the changes are OK. But, for example, the question was already deleted by the asker.

Doing a facelift of a question when that does not solve any problems is not a useful task to be done.

When you have [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) then you can edit such questions without burdening the review queue.

I still suggest doing it sparingly. I personally edit close-worthy questions when it seems that it might help OP when they do edit themselves. For example, if it seems like they struggle with formatting or creating a Stack snippet.