# Flag approved edits to bad questions

Tags: discussion, edits

In *[Is it appropriate to edit and properly format a really bad question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278479/is-it-appropriate-to-edit-and-properly-format-a-really-bad-question)* it is said that edits to obviously bad questions are discouraged.

Then I stumbled over this (to my mind really bad) question: 
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018928/how-to-put-partcles-between-two-positions-formula*

An edit was made to put the linked picture into the post. To my mind this question is off-topic and very low quality, so the edit is just a waste of time and blocking the review queue. Still, it got approved, as it is a minor improvement, but the question is still unsalvageable to my mind.

Should this be reported somehow?

Picture of the post if the question gets deleted:

[image: Picture of question in question]

Comment: I do not know how often moderators talk to reviewers that are not being caught by audits but still doing a questionable job. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19544567) two should have done better, IMO. The question is going to be deleted eventually, so not lasting harm was done.

Comment: Generally these should be rejected because edits by anyone (other than the close voters) to a closed post will push into the reopen queue where reviewers will have to waste time on it. Luckily the edit went through before closure

Comment: @yivi I like to avoid name calling thats why I did not mention the reviewers.

Comment: You've linked the post and by doing that named the editor... The remaining  information was one click away. And real problem are the reviewers IMO. Good reviewers catch these cases before they become a problem.

Comment: What are the actual effects of the edit? If the question isn't closed yet does this remove any pending flags/votes?

Comment: @AndréKool no... but in such scenarios, it is highly likely the suggested edit gets approved after the post is closed.

Comment: @SurajRao And instantly put it in the reopen queue? (when it is accepted after being closed)

Comment: @AndréKool yes...and once reviewers have voted to leave closed, any subsequent improvements made by OP will not send it to the reopen queue again

Comment: Not sure this one is the best of examples. It looks like a  good faith edit as the OP can't themselves inline the image and while the end result is still poor - at least the OP may stand a chance of adding additional information related to the image based on any comments. It's probably overall a futile exercise and not worth the time of doing it but it's done now and it strikes me as the editor thought it might help and so did the reviewers. Was it worth doing - most likely not. Is it a persistent problem that's harmful - no.

Comment: Re-activating excessively bad content is pretty harmful.  I pinged the reviewers.

Comment: The reviewers have a pretty high Approve/Reject ratio. We really need to instruct our reviewers better.

Comment: @S.L.Barth such a ratio is not more than a vague indicator, not a sufficent tool too evaluate review-quality.

Comment: @HansPassant [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50018928/timeline) shows that edit happened almost immediately after posting, this hardly qualifies as reactivating

Comment: @KamiKaze I;ve found that a 5:1 or higher Approve/Reject ratio is actually a pretty good indicator. Not proof, but enough ground for closer inspection. I've caught my share of robo-reviewers that way.

Comment: @JonClements sure I can see good will (with a bit off repwhoring sprinkeld over it, but hey I am guilty of this too). The question is how to handle this, I am not eager to flag for moderator attention. But a notification that such things are discouraged will in the long run improve quality of SO. This is by no means something I would say anybody was doing something obviously wrong or with a bad intent.

Comment: @gnat this getting through triage in the first place is a much bigger offense, than anything discussed here......

Comment: @KamiKaze [dreaded Triage guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366334/839601), business as usual. "Requires Editing = can be improved with edits by author", when will this madness stop. By author, gimme a f#cking break

Comment: I was one of the editors. The edit included the image in the question, which before I couldn't see. It showed even more the poor quality of the question and I downvoted and voted to close the question. IMO those are the appropriate tools. I am not aware/didn't know that approving edits change the questions status, which all the negative comments are about; I believe that shouldn't. It is an (unwanted?) side-effect of the edit process.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, if a suggested edit doesn't push the question quality beyond the "closabe" threshold, it's a kinda pointless edit to begin with. What is sometime called "polishing a turd", as in you can polish it, but will remain a "turd". It's better to reject those suggestions, so people can learn to focus on salvageable posts to begin with.

Comment: @yivi, as I said, "_which before I couldn't see_". But I agree with you in principle.

Comment: *...when will this madness stop...* @gnat At approximately 02:46:20Z April 25th, 2018. (Though I imagine it's still going to take time for folks to realize the guidance has changed.)

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't report this. The edit itself is fine (it does make a minor improvement). I doubt a mod flag here would be sustained.

I might be inclined to reject the edit, but I can't fault the reviewers either. It's not a bad edit. The reason I would reject the edit is that it doesn't actually fix the question. I would reject it as **No Improvement** so that a close vote wouldn't put this into the Reopen queue.

Reserve mod flags for bad edits and approvals for

1. A reviewer selects Edit in a review queue and fails to address the reason it was there (editing typically removes it from the queue). I had a LQP flag recently where a new(2k) reviewer edited a link-only answer and only added bolding to the link. Mods didn't seem to like that edit either.
2. The reviewers were also asleep at the wheel. These should be **clearly bad edits** and not simply edits like this that are attempts to make improvement

Comment: There is a reason for rejecting the edit; posting images instead of formatted code is strongly discouraged. Editing a post to make this error more visible is no good and a wrong edit IMHO.

Comment: @FallenAngel Remember, the question was if the OP should flag this. And I already said I would have rejected it myself for not making the question answerable

Comment: @FallenAngel The image is of a hand drawn graph, not a screenshot of code. It's true we don't want screenshots of text and even this image should have had alt text (the edit is pointless for anyone who can't see the image) describing it but the image itself is an actual graphic, not inaccessible text.

Comment: I rejected the edit because _no freehand circles_

Comment: @BSMP ah now I see the picture (: